# How to store text content of a browser textarea on a local disk

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I need to store edited "textarea" text ( > 1 MB ) temporarily on a local disk to work offline. Later I want to load it again and continue editing, just like a with common desktop apps.
I know I can load textfiles easily and add it to an textarea. But how to save it ?
I'v red a lot in blogs about this issue and there are some serious workaround proposals like IndexdDB and Web SQL Storage. But which one is working on **all** major browsers and will be supported in the (near) future ? I did not find any current clear statement yet.

Comment: Local storage is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the host's (`window`) [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) object, specifically the [`localStorage` variant](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) (since the `sessionStorage` variant is only retained -you might have guessed it- during a session).
It is supported by all modern browsers (by the specifications) and will usually hold 5 MB.

You could try the following example in [w3schools editor](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic) (because it will not work on stack-snippets, jsfiddle, realtime-html-editor etc. due to security reasons).
Also note that it will not work in locally saved web-pages, as currently browsers still need a fully qualified domain-name in order to apply security-measures *and* link storage (also cookies etc.) to the proper domain!
That's why I mentioned the dreaded w3schools (as I couldn't find something where this would work without having webhosting up and running).
Finally, above 'justification' is also intended to explain why examples you might have tried locally didn't work.
A final work-around is setting up a local webserver and point your browser to the (local) IP-address, thereby solving the 'problem' where browsers need a valid domain to link the storage to!!!
<sup>(I'm very fond of [tiny](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/) for quick and portable local fiddeling around with such code that requires a valid URL.)</sup>

Here is the mentioned (tested) code to get you started: <sup>(comments should explain it)</sup>

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="save_my_txt" placeholder="Enter text here.."></textarea>
  <input type="reset" value="reset">
</form>

<script>
(function(elm, key){
  // check for local storage support
  if(window.localStorage){
    // if there was data stored, retrieve it and output it to the elment
    if(localStorage.getItem(key)) elm.value=localStorage.getItem(key);
    // when the element is blurred and the content is changed
    elm.onchange=function(){
      // check if the textarea is empty and save or remove localStorage entry
      localStorage[this.value?'setItem':'removeItem'](key, this.value);
    };
    // finally, a form's reset does NOT fire it's element's onchange()
    // either 'fix' the reset-button (using `this.form.reset()`)
    // or the form's `onreset` handler (example below:)
    elm.form.onreset=function(){ localStorage.removeItem(key); };
  } // else handle the lack of Storage-support differently..
}( document.getElementById('save_my_txt')  // pass in a textarea
 , 'my_txt_str'                            // pass key-identifier for localStorage
 )
); //end IIFE
</script>
```

Note that since you already requested modern/future browser support, I used the html5 `placeholder` (alleviating some javascript required to correctly manipulate `defaultValue` for resets etc).

Hope this helps!!